# How to use handlebars-loader in a Create React App project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handlebars.js, create-react-app, webpack-handlebars-loader

I'd like to import a `Handlebars` file as a template in my CRA project.

This is my current setup, adapted from [React-App- Rewired won't add Babel Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912881/react-app-rewired-wont-add-babel-plugin), [handlebars-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-loader), and [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra)

**config-overrides.js**

```js
const { override } = require('customize-cra');

const addHandleBarsLoader = config => {
    config.module.rules.push(
        { test: /\.handlebars$/, loader: "handlebars-loader" }
    );
    return config;
}

module.exports = override(
    addHandleBarsLoader
);
```

on the 3rd line here i get `TypeError: template is not a function`

```js
const template = require("./test.handlebars");
console.log(template);
const htmlString = template(data);
```

console:

`/static/media/test.a9cd7544.handlebars`

**package.json**

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
...
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is in `test.handlebars`? What does it export?

Comment: @76484 it doesn't export anything, it's just a handlebars template, like `<p>{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</p>` in https://handlebarsjs.com/examples/simple-expressions.html